# Fonts, goes back to default size

Tags: java, swing, fonts, actionlistener

Every time I change the font, it goes back to the default size, which is 12, even if I change it before with the "Tamano" menu, it only goes back to 12 every time, my guess would be the way I change the size with deriveFont(), but don't I now any other way to change it.

```
public static class cambiar extends JFrame {

    public cambiar() {
        final Font aryal = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Cambios en el Texto!");
        JPanel adentro = new JPanel();
        final JLabel texto = new JLabel("Texto a Cambiar!");
        texto.setFont(aryal);
        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fuentes = new JMenu("Fuentes");
        /* Elementos de Fuentes */
        JMenuItem arial = new JMenuItem("Arial");
        arial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Font arrrial = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12);
                float tam = (float) texto.getFont().getSize();
                String hola = String.valueOf(tam);
                texto.setFont(arrrial);
                texto.setFont(texto.getFont().deriveFont(tam));
            }
        });



        fuentes.add(arial);
        /* FIN Fuentes */


        JMenu tamano = new JMenu("Tamano");

        /* Elementos de Tamano */
        JMenuItem font13 = new JMenuItem("13");
        font13.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto.setFont(texto.getFont().deriveFont(23.0f));
            }
        });

        JMenuItem font14 = new JMenuItem("14");
        arial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto.setFont(aryal);
            }
        });

        JMenuItem font15 = new JMenuItem("15");
        arial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto.setFont(aryal);
            }
        });

        JMenuItem font16 = new JMenuItem("16");
        arial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto.setFont(aryal);
            }
        });

        JMenuItem font17 = new JMenuItem("17");
        arial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto.setFont(aryal);
            }
        });

        JMenuItem font18 = new JMenuItem("18");
        arial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto.setFont(aryal);
            }
        });

        JMenuItem font19 = new JMenuItem("19");
        arial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto.setFont(aryal);
            }
        });

        JMenuItem font20 = new JMenuItem("20");
        arial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto.setFont(aryal);
            }
        });

        tamano.add(font13);
        /* FIN tanano */

        JMenu tipo = new JMenu("Tipo");

        /* Elementos de tipo */

        /* FIN tipo */


        /* Elementos del JMENU */
        menu.add(fuentes);
        menu.add(tamano);
        menu.add(tipo);
        /* FIN JMENU */

        /* Elementos del JPanel */
        adentro.add(menu);
        adentro.add(texto);
        /* FIN JPanel */

        /* Elementos del JFRAME */
        ventana.add(adentro);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        ventana.setSize(250, 250);
        /* FIN JFRAME */        
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The listeners on your JMenuItems set the font to `aryal`, which has font size 12. Where are you actually trying to change the size?

Comment: In the Jmenuitem font13, I set It to 23.0f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you really just need one action listener:

```
private class MenuListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object caller = e.getSource();
        if (caller != null && caller.instanceOf JMenuItem) {
            JMenuItem src = (JMenuItem)caller;
            String size = src.getText();

            if (size != null) {
                float fontSize = Float.parseFloat(size);
                texto.setFont(aryal.deriveFont(fontSize));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you create your JMenuItems:

```
MenuListener listener = new MenuListener();
JMenuItem font18 = new JMenuItem("18");
font18.setActionListener(listener);
```

The `deriveFont` method returns the font set to the specified size, but it doesn't actually *change* the font itself. Therefore you need to call `setFont` with the newly sized font.

In general to change the font size:

```
Font font; // some font you already have instantiated
float size = 20f; // the target font size
Font newFont = font.deriveFont(size); // the newly sized font
```

**EDIT**

In response to the question, the above `MenuListener` code either needs to go in its own class called MenuListener.java (but you have to make it `public`) *or* you'd put it in the class `cambiar`:

```
public class cambiar extends JFrame { 
    ... your existing code here ...

    private class MenuListener implements ActionListener {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I declare "private ActionListener MenuListener"?

Comment: @BladimirRuiz I've edited my response to explain where to put the MenuListener class code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in the `addActionListener()` method you're ending up adding the same aryal `font`.

I would suggest a modification like this:

```
.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                texto.setFont(aryal.deriveFont(size)); //where size is the size that you want to set
            }
        });
```

For example, if you would want to change the `font` size to 20, you might want to do something like this:

```
JMenuItem font20 = new JMenuItem("20");
font20.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        texto.setFont(aryal.deriveFont(20));
    }
});
```

Note: Here I'm assuming that you're trying to change the font size of the `JLabel` *texto*. But the idea would be the same wherever you want to use it.